# yup update schema with new validation fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I am currently generating a number of input fields based on the number the user has passed. So if user entered 2 then this will generate 2 sets of user input fields.

```
const addRowsToSvlanConfg = () => {
    const isErrors = Object.keys(errors).length !== 0;
    const svlanConfigdynamicArray = [];

    if (!isErrors && noOfGPONCardsState > 0 && noOfGPONCardsState <= 15) {
      for (let index = 0; index < noOfGPONCardsState; index++) {
        const svlanConfigNewdynamicArray = {
          oltSvlan: `oLTSVLAN${index}`,
          bngContainerName: `bNGContainer${index}`,
          bngSvlan: `bNGSVLANs${index}`,
          eviNumber: `eVInumber${index}`,
          oltSlot: `oLTSlot${index}`,
          cardModel: `cardModel${index}`,
        };
        svlanConfigdynamicArray.push(svlanConfigNewdynamicArray);
      }

      setSvlanConfigFields(svlanConfigdynamicArray);
    }
  };
```

I am currently using react-hook-form along with Yup for the validation. My problems I want to added validation to those fields that have been generated above.

```
const createOrderSchema = yup.object().shape({
    inpTicketID: yup
      .string()
      .trim()
      .min(4, '* Please enter minimum of 4 characters')
      .max(7, '* Please enter maximum of 7 characters')
      .matches('^([Tt][Gg])[A-Za-z0-9]*', '* Ticket ID must start with TG and it should be Alphanumeric')
      .required('* Please enter Ticket ID'),
  });
```

This is my current Yup schema but I am not sure how to further add validation to the fields that were generated based on user input.

This is how i am displaying the input

```
{svlanConfFields
    ? svlanConfFields.map((value, idx) => (
        <TableBody key={idx}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <TextField
                inputRef={register}
                name={`oLTSVLAN${idx}`}
                className={classes.textField}
                InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
                onKeyUp={() => onOLTSVLANConfigKeyup(idx)}
                fullWidth
              />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      ))
    : null}
```

```
 const { register, trigger, handleSubmit, reset, errors, getValues, control } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(createOrderSchema),
    mode: 'onChange',
    reValidateMode: 'onChange',
  });
```

This is how i am adding my schema to react-hook-form. Any help would be much appreciated.